# Windows 10 file explorer: find files and folders with brackets in their names

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On a shared LAN-drive I want use special keywords within brackets in the names of files and folders to flag them for later automated tidying actions.
e.g. :

- {bin} as a name for a folder that serves as a local trash.
- {temp} for temporary files or folders.
- {a2024} for a file or folder that ought to be archived in 2024
- {z2024-10} for a file or folder that ought to be compressed (zipped) after October 2024
- {d2024-10-25} for a file or folder that ought to be deleted after October, 25th, 2024.

I put these flags keywords within brackets for a mere reason : nobody ever use brackets in file or folder names.

I developed this method with my Linux desktop. Then, using the file explorer to find these flagged files and folders is easy.

But I have troubles with doing the same with Windows 10 file explorer.

**Problem 1 : hard drive vs network drives**

In the search field, to find all the flagged files and folders, i.e. all items with a couple of opening and closing brackets, I type `"*{*}*` . More simply, I can use `"*{*` to find all items matching an opening bracket.
This works on my local hard drive but does not work and the shared

**Problem 2 : being more selective**

If I wish to search for all the items that ought to be archived, i.e. those with `{a(somedate)}` in their name. How do I do this, even on y local hard drive ?
I thought I would simply use `"*{a*}*` but it returns a list of items with or without brackets (but actually no folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for special characters (both on a hard drive and network drive), you can simply put the search term between `~="` and `"`, where `~=` means contains according to an [archived Windows help page](http://web.archive.org/web/20160622085239/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows).

So for you first problem the search term would be `~="*{*}*"`, and for your second it would be `~="*{a*}*"`.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks !

Comment: More precisely, the tilde `~ ` serves a "switch" tfor search to process `?` and `*` as wildcards when they appear within quotation marks,